# Java bug? Why draws rectangle instead of ellipse?

Tags: java, swing, scale, java-2d

The code below draws rectangle and 2 ellipses.

[image]

While should draw 3 ellipses.

My OS is Windows 7 prof 64 bit

My Java is 1.6 x86 also 1.7 x64 tested.

Why?

```
package tests;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class AntialiacingScaleTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {

                JPanel circlePanel = new JPanel() {
                    @Override
                    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

                        super.paintComponent(g);

                        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
                        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                        g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
                        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                        //g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 200, 200);
                        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 200));

                        AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();

                        g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                        g2d.scale(1000, 1000);
                        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.001f));
                        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 0.225, 0.225));

                        g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                        g2d.scale(10, 10);
                        g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.001f));
                        g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 0.025, 0.025));

                        g2d.setTransform(old);

                    }
                };

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


                //frame.setLayout(new MigLayout("fill"));
                //frame.add(circlePanel, "w 300, h 300, grow");

                //frame.add(circlePanel);

                frame.setLayout(null);
                circlePanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300));
                frame.add(circlePanel);

                frame.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 300);

                //frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: 1) `g2d.scale(10000, 10000);`  Why the huge scaling? 2) `new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paint(Graphics g)` should be `new JPanel() {
                @Override
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` 3) The first line of that method should typically call `super` e.g.  `super.paintComponent(g)`.

Comment: @Andrew (1) for test (2,3) didn't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I copy/pasted your code and it drew the 2 ellipses you wrote about, the only change I made was to replace your `MigLayout` by `null`, set the frame and panel dimensions by hand and remove the `frame.pack()` invocation:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel circlePanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                //g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 200, 200);
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 200));

                AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();

                g2d.scale(10000, 10000);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(0.001f));
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 0.025, 0.025));

                g2d.setTransform(old);

            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(null);
        circlePanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300));
        frame.add(circlePanel);

        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 300);

        //frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

[image]

**Update:** 
Could reproduce the problem using the Oracle JDK (java version "1.8.0-ea") instead of the OpenJDK. Got the diamond shape, as pointed out in another answers, the scale factor is the root cause of the shape degenaration, don't know if that should be the appropiate behaviour though, so, there must be a bug in one these JRE's. 
The following test program works fine for both JRE's:

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel circlePanel = new JPanel() {
            @Override
            public void paint(Graphics g) {

                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
                g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1));
                //g2d.drawOval(0, 0, 200, 200);
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 200, 200));

                AffineTransform old = g2d.getTransform();

                g2d.scale(10, 10);
                g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(1.0f));
                g2d.draw(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, 25.0, 25.0));

                g2d.setTransform(old);

            }
        };

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setLayout(null);
        circlePanel.setBounds(new Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 300));
        frame.add(circlePanel);

        frame.setBounds(0, 0, 350, 300);

        //frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"replace your `MigLayout` by a `NullLayout`"*  1) There is no `NullLayout` class as that string suggests. 2) The panel should return a preferred size, for the layout manager to have a dimension to work with.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, indeed, I dit mean to replace the `MigLayout` by just `null`, corrected in the answer

Comment: @h3nr1x what OS&Java do you have

Comment: I'm getting the same results using both codes in 1.6.0  (once the other compiled) & 1.7.0_09 (using just your code), a square instead of an ellipse.

Comment: I'm using linux with the OpenJDK version 1.7.0_09

Answer (score 1):

Replicated on Java 7, Windows 7 in Eclipse, removing the Layout Manager.

My feeling is that it's due to the combination of the high scaling and inaccuracies at small floating point values, reducing the number of points generated.

If you substitute values you find between 0.0363 and 0.0362 the rendering API breaks. It no longer generates an Arc, but instead a square.

The work-around is to stop combining the huge scaling with tiny sized objects. Scale down and increase the size.